# port isolation with bazel and linux

Tags: linux, sandbox, bazel

Trying to test out port isolation with bazel and linux and it fails.

My env is as following (started on aws):

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

$ uname -mrs
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64
```

Bazel version

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.5.1
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue Jun 6 10:34:11 2017 (1496745251)
Build timestamp: 1496745251
Build timestamp as int: 1496745251
```

The repo: https://github.com/ittaiz/bazel-port-isolation

Running the test:
$ bazel test //...

```
____Loading package:
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/cpp
____Loading package: @local_config_xcode//
____Loading package: @local_jdk//
____Loading package: @local_config_cc//
____Loading complete.  Analyzing...
____Loading package: tools/defaults
____Loading package: @bazel_tools//tools/test
____Loading package: @junit_junit//jar
____Found 2 test targets...
____Building...
____[0 / 12] Expanding template SocketIsolation2Test
____[10 / 12] Building SocketIsolationTest.jar (1 source file)
FAIL: //:SocketIsolation2Test (see /home/builduser/.cache/bazel/_bazel_builduser/a589c0f8758972ab3aadcf172c468873/execroot/bazel-port-isolation/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/testlogs/SocketIsolation2Test/test.log)
PASS: //:SocketIsolationTest
____Elapsed time: 11.152s, Critical Path: 7.03s
//:SocketIsolationTest                                                   PASSED in 5.3s
//:SocketIsolation2Test                                                  FAILED in 0.3s
  /home/builduser/.cache/bazel/_bazel_builduser/a589c0f8758972ab3aadcf172c468873/execroot/bazel-port-isolation/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/testlogs/SocketIsolation2Test/test.log
```

(As you can see  - no sandbox failure or warnings)

The tet log show **"Address already in use"** - which means that there were no port isolation.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out why...

From here: https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#sandboxing

> On some platforms such as Google Container Engine cluster nodes or
>   Debian, user namespaces are deactivated by default due to security
>   concerns. This can be checked by looking at the file
>   /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone: if it exists and contains
>   a 0, then user namespaces can be activated with sudo sysctl
>   kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1.

The `/proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone` existed and had 0 in it.. . so changing it according to the insturction solved it.